# Using "React Testing library" - How to wrap all my test component with providers

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-testing-library, redux-toolkit

I'm using React-Testing-Library and I have my `main.tsx` file like this with all the Redux-Toolkit and React-Router wrappers as follows:

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Suspense fallback={<LoadingSpinner />}>
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/*" element={<App />} />
            </Routes>
          </BrowserRouter>
        </Suspense>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
);
```

Now, when I try to test any component that uses any `useDispatch` or `useNavigate` the test fails unless I wrap that component with the providers like this:

```
test("Inputs should be initially empty", () => {
  render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Login />
      </BrowserRouter>
      ,
    </Provider>,
  );
  const emailInput: HTMLInputElement = screen.getByRole("textbox", {
    name: /email/i,
  });
  expect(emailInput.value).toBe("");
});
```

Now, the test has passed and everything is good.

My question is, is there a way to initially wrap all the components I'm going to test by default with these wrappers? So that I don't have to wrap all my test components with these every time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a [wrapper](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api/#wrapper) component that renders any providers and wraps the `children` prop.

```
const ProviderWrapper = ({ children }) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      {children}
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
);
```

```
test("Inputs should be initially empty", () => {
  render(<Login />, { wrapper: ProviderWrapper });

  const emailInput: HTMLInputElement = screen.getByRole("textbox", {
    name: /email/i,
  });

  expect(emailInput.value).toBe("");
});
```

If you just need to wrap ***every*** component you test with the same providers then you can also create a [custom `render` function](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup/#custom-render).

Example:

```
import {render} from '@testing-library/react';

const ProviderWrapper = ({ children }) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      {children}
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
);

const customRender = (ui, options) =>
  render(ui, { wrapper: ProviderWrapper, ...options });

// re-export everything
export * from '@testing-library/react';

// override render method
export { customRender as render };
```

```
test("Inputs should be initially empty", () => {
  render(<Login />); // <-- custom render already wraps with providers

  const emailInput: HTMLInputElement = screen.getByRole("textbox", {
    name: /email/i,
  });

  expect(emailInput.value).toBe("");
});
```